# Adding a custom method to CRUDReposity interface in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'd like to add a method that finds a Todo item based on a given description. Online people are saying you can use JSQL and that Spring will automatically implement it. I tried the following:

```
public interface TodoRepo extends CrudRepository<Todo, Long> {

@Query("SELECT t FROM Todo t WHERE t.description=:description")
Todo findByDescription(@Param("description") String description);
}
```

However, I got an error saying that the symbol "@Query" could not be found. Is there some wiring or importing I'm failing to do? Is there another way to implement a custom method? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

Comment: Just read this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Apart from any dependency problems that you’re obviously having. It is sufficient to just write an unannotated method `findByDescription(String description)` to have Spring data JPA implement it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with your dependencies and or imports.

The `@Query` annotation is part of Spring Data JPA, which you intend to use.

There are two things you have to verify:

1. Spring Data JPA is on the classpath
2. You are importing `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`

If you update your question with your Maven configuration or comparable and/or a more complete java file including the imports we might give more detailed advice.